# Solve the initial value problem $ \ y'(t) +(\sin (t)) y=\sin t $

Tags: initial-value-problems

Solve the initial value problem  $ \ y'(t) +(\sin (t)) y=\sin t $ ,  $ \ y(0)=7 \ $ , $ 0 \leq t \leq \pi $ $$ $$ How can I solve this initial value problem . Any hints please

Comment: Use the Integrating Factor method, perhaps?

Comment: Check out [linear differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation). There is a direct closed form solution for [first order case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients).

Comment: But this is nono-linear equation , is not it?

Comment: No, this is linear. Any equation of the form $y'(t) + a(t)y(t) = p(t)$ is linear. Nonlinear equations are those where the unknown $y$ shows up in some nonlinear way; for example, $y'(t) + \sin(t) y = \sin(y)$ is nonlinear as is $y'(t) = 1+ y(t)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The form of the equation is: $y'(t) + f(t)y = g(t)$, well suited for Integrating factor method.

We have

$f(t) = \sin(t)$, consider the integrating factor $\displaystyle e^{\int f(t)dt} = e^{-\cos(t)}$

Answer (score 1):

Try using integrating factor method with integrating factor $e^{\int \sin(t)dt}$. Then after multiplying through you can rewrite the equation as 
$$\frac{d}{dt} ( e^{-\cos(t)}y(t))=e^{-\cos(t)}\sin(t)$$
Integrating with respect to $t$ (with a $u$-substitution, $u=-\cos(t)$), we get
$$e^{-\cos(t)}y(t)=e^{-\cos(t)}+c$$
and so our general solution for $y$ is 
$$y(t)=1+c e^{\cos(t)}$$

Now using the initial value condition we can solve for $c$:
$$y(0)=1 +ce=7$$
and solving for $c$ we get 
$$c=\frac{6}{e}$$ and the particular solution is:

$$y(t)=1
+\frac{6}{e}e^{\cos(t)}=1+6e^{\cos(t)-1}$$